# Apache server consume more memory while Apache log split

Tags: memory, apache-http-server

**Issue 1: Apache consuming more than 50% memory within 1 minute on specific time by every day**

I have checked this issue in details by verify apache log and also review all files from my code but now not an issue with code files as it running for 24x7 but memory consume time is specific on day.

I have also checked cron timing but no cron execute at same time.

Here, I have also provided details on apache server configuration which I have setup at /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf

```
StartServers             5
MinSpareServers       5
MaxSpareServers      10
MaxRequestWorkers     150
ServerLimit         128
MaxClients          128
MaxConnectionsPerChild   100
```

**Issue 2: Server consuming all memory as time passed and need to reboot server withing 24 hours**

Once server consume xxxMB amount of memory then it can't release that memory and when we checked it by every 30 minutes then there can be flctuation of +/- 50MB but in most of the case, it reduces fluently and we have no memory by 24 hours.

When we try top or htop command then it just list out apache on top so we only get the idea that apache consuming more memory but didn't get an exact idea of which process consuming memory now and it seems like old process not release that memory.

FYI:

1. I have installed apache on ubuntu 16
2. One PHP website is running on this apache server
3. Server having 2GB RAM, previously it was 1 GB but still issue not fixed.
4. Website was working fine before 1 Month ago. We have not done any major changes from code or from server side by this time period and many are also undo now so it almost same like before. Number of live users are also not increased by last month.

Can anyone help on to trace and fix exact issue?